# How to query nested mongodb fields efficiently in Java?

Tags: java, performance, mongodb

I'm not very experienced with running Mongo queries from Java, so I'm no expert at commands. I have a Mongo collection with ~6500 documents, each containing multiple fields (some of which have sub-fields), like below:

```
"_id" : NumberLong(714847),
"franchiseIds" : [
    NumberLong(714848),
    NumberLong(714849)
],
"profileSettings" : {
    "DISCLAIMER_SETUP" : {
        "settingType" : "DISCLAIMER_SETUP",
        "attributeMap" : {
...
```

I want to have an operation which will go through the entire collection from time to time and calculate how many franchiseIds are present, since different documents could have anywhere from 1 to 4 franchiseIds.

From the Mongo shell, I did a very simple script to get this, and it calculated the result immediately:

```
rs_default:SECONDARY> var totalCount = 0;
rs_default:SECONDARY> db.profiles.find().forEach( function(profile) { totalCount += profile.franchiseIds.length } );
rs_default:SECONDARY> totalCount
```

However, when I attempted to do the same thing in Java, which is where this would run on the server from time to time, it was much less performant, taking around 15 seconds to complete:

```
int result = 0;
List<Profile> allProfiles = mongoTemplate.findAll(Profile.class, PROFILE_COLLECTION);
for (Profile profile : allProfiles) {
    result += profile.getFranchiseIds().size();
}

return results
```

I realize the above isn't performant in Java as it's having to allocate memory for all of the Profiles being loaded in. In the Mongo shell script, is Mongo simply taking care of this itself?

Any ideas how I can do something similar in Java?

EDIT:
I returned only the franchiseIds field on the response from Mongo, and that helped significantly. Below is the improved code:

```
final Query query = new Query();
query.fields().include(FRANCHISE_IDS);

final List<Profile> allProfiles = mongoTemplate.find(query, Profile.class, PROFILE_COLLECTION);
for (Profile profile : allProfiles) {
    result += profile.getFranchiseIds().size();
}

return result;
```

Comment: The Java version is slower because it has to transfer all the selected records from the DB to the client so it can iterate over them. You could speed up the Java version by providing Select criteria and only returning the FranchiseId arrays since this is all you need.

Comment: Thanks, that did speed things up quite a bit. Went from ~15 seconds to ~1100ms.